# Does bootstrap 4 come with !important?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-specificity

Although I have placed `style.css` file after Bootstrap, but it does not work. When I inspected, I noticed that...

[image: css]

Now how I can fixed this problem.

```
.bg-info{
     background-color: #17a2b8 !important;
}
```

Comment: It's rather hard to understand what you have tried so far. Can show us how you've used the `style.css` file? Where did you place it?

Comment: You can use its parent class to change its value.

Comment: See CSS Specifity: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: Yes Bootstrap uses '!important'. There's no problem with the way you placed your css. Just add a custom class to your element and override the style. Ex: .my-ele.bg-info {background-color: #000}

Answer (score 1):

You can use its parent class to change its value.

```
.bg .bg-info {background-color:none!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you style with "!important" so non of the style can change this..

So you to use the same "!important" in style.css whatever color you want to show.

And mention the element name before the class name.

Style.css:-

```
div.bg-info{
Background-color:blue !important;
}
p.bg-info{
Background-color:blue !important;
}
h1.bg-info{
Background-color:blue !important;
}
span.bg-info{
Background-color:blue !important;
}
```

Because the style.css calling after the Bootstrap.

Comment: This doesn't work, you should add a space between these two classes unless it is used on a same line!!

Comment: Yes, so we can mention the element name before the class name.